# How to make a non-blocking connection close in r2dbc?

Tags: r2dbc

How to make a non-blocking connection close?

```
Flux<Row> connectToDatabase(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, String query) {
        return Mono.from(connectionFactory.create())
                .flatMapMany(connection ->
                        Flux.from(connection.createStatement(query).execute())
                                .flatMap(result -> result.map((row, metadata) -> row))
                                .doFinally((signalType) ->  Mono.from(connection.close()).subscribe())
                );
    }
```

Connection.close is publisher and I don't understand how to close the connection and pass Flux and Connection.

You can pass Flux<Tuple2<Row, Connection>>, and then manipulate, but it seems to me that this is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
private Flux<Row> connectToDatabase(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, String query) {
        return Flux.usingWhen(connectionFactory.create(),
                connection -> Flux.from(connection.createStatement(query).execute())
                                .flatMap(result -> result.map((row, metadata) -> row)),
                Connection::close);
    }
```